# RxJava2 Convert result of map to Flowable?

Tags: java, android, rx-java2, rx-android

What operator can I use to convert this `Single<Flowable<T>>` to `Flowable<T>`?

I see things like "flattenAsFlowable" but I don't think that's the one, as seems to operate on/with iterables? `toFlowable()` returns something like `Flowable<Flowable<T>>` which is not good either?

Not even sure why does map now put my flowable into a single? I understand that there will be only one item but it makes my types (and dependent classes) mismatch.

[image]

Comment: flatMapPublisher instead of map
http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#flatMapPublisher-io.reactivex.functions.Function-

Answer (score 0):

use

```
.flatMap{.....

return ....
}`
```

instead of :

```
.map{.....

return ....
}
```